# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS においてGPU 2080Tiのドライバーが適用されない

Tags: ubuntu, gpu

Ubuntu 18.04のGeForce 2080TiにNVIDIAのGPUドライバーを入れようといろいろなサイトを見て試しましたが

```
nvidia-smi
```

を入力して

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.14 Driver Version: 430.14 CUDA Version: 10.2 |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|

| 0 GeForce RTX 208... Off | 00000000:43:00.0 Off | N/A |
|ERR! 37C P0 N/A N/A | 0MiB / 10986MiB | 0% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: GPU Memory |
| GPU PID Type Process name Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| No running processes found
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

のように出力され、ERR!という部分が出てしまいます。
何か解決策をご存じの方はいないでしょうか？

ドライババージョン、Ubuntu16、カーネルはすべて試して,Ubuntu 18.04 LTS(4.18.0-22- generic) 430.14がうまくいきました。
他に何か必要な情報等あれば教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

Qiitaの[Ubuntu16.04のRTX2080Tiの対応するNvidia Driverのインストール](https://qiita.com/sey323/items/be1d18a0b922d71c5b4e)　という記事(苦労談)は読まれましたか？
カーネルの変更が必要とか、参考になる情報が書かれているように思います。

Comment: 16でカーネル変更もしましたができませんでした。